# Exclude current post from "recent posts widget"

Tags: wordpress

In a plugin for displaying recent posts in your sidebar widget, how can we apply a filter to the plugin's functions.php so that it won't include the current page/post in the display?

The plugin author replied, before he entered a long silence: "You can add custom parameter to the `rpwe_default_query_arguments` filter. Just add `exclude => get_the_ID()` to the filter."

Is it here, that we add it?

```
// Allow plugins/themes developer to filter the default query.
    $query = apply_filters( 'rpwe_default_query_arguments', $query );
```

How?

This is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/

---

I found [some guidance](http://themeshaper.com/2009/05/03/filters-wordpress-child-themes/) that appears to be quite simple
but then it results in errors in my site (localhost) while trying to correct the syntax.  `=>` seems to be not correctly used.

This is what I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'rpwe_default_query_arguments', 'rpwe_exclude_current' );
function rpwe_exclude_current ( $query ) {
    'exclude' => get_the_ID()
    $posts = new WP_Query( $query );
    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that worked in my situation:

```
add_filter( 'rpwe_default_query_arguments', 'my_function_name' );
function my_function_name( $args ) {
    if( is_singular() && !isset( $args['post__in'] ) )
    $args['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );
    return $args;
}
```

Here is [the site](http://www.billerickson.net/code/display-posts-exclude-current-post/) where I found it.